# Why do I get permission denied In my Firestore app code but the Firestore console test works?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have been having some trouble understanding firestore rules.

I have wrote the following rules in my Firestore database. When I run a test in the console using an authenticated user ID to update a restaurant entity, the test passes with success. However when I try to make this call in Kotlin using the SDK, after authenticating with Google sign in, I get Permission Denied. What have I missed?

```
    function userIsAdmin(restaurantId) {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/restaurants/$(restaurantId)/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == "Owner";
    }

    match /restaurants/{restaurantId} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if userIsAdmin(restaurantId);
    }

    match /restaurants/{restaurantId}/menus/{menuId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if true;
    }

    match /restaurants/{restaurantId}/users/{userId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

User entity on firestore:
[image: User entity on firestore]

Query in Kotlin:

```
firestore.collection(COLLECTION_RESTAURANT)
.document("aXTSlGphPbzAXRInHBIg")
.update(KEY_RESTAURANT_NAME, "New restaurant")
.await()
```

Comment: Since we can't see the UID of the current signed in user, it's not possible to say for sure.  Be sure to log that UID just before the query to make sure it contains the value you expect.  I'll also point out that the values you have for user IDs don't look like actual Firebase Auth user IDs.

Comment: Ahhh yes! I'm using the uid from native Google Auth, rather than firebase Auth. So the uid must be null when I'm making the query! Thank you !

Comment: @Indiana did changing to Firebase Auth IDs solved the issue?

Comment: @ralemos yes that solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @DougStevenson on the comments, the problem is that you are storing native Google Auth IDs instead of Firebase Auth user IDs in your `users` collection, and Firebase Auth user IDs when querying, because of that the uid on the query will either come out as `null` or `undefined` and cause these permission issues.

If you change the firestore records to use Firebase Auth user Ids on your `users` collection, it will fix the issue.